# create a database with scala/lift and a simple interface to log in

Tags: database, logging, scala, lift

I'm a beginner with scala/lift and POO.
At first, i would like to create a database and a simple interface to log in (ID and password).
Then create an application to allow the user to modify this database.

My problem is: i didn't find anything (like a tutorial) to do something like that.

Maybe somebody could help?

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's the  [lift book](http://the-lift-book.googlegroups.com/web/master.pdf?), the [website](http://www.liftweb.net), and of course [the google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb).  The book being the best place to get started.

Answer (score 0):

See lift's demo application at [github](https://github.com/lift/examples/blob/master/combo/example/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala). The file creates an object `DBVendor` which handles the connection creation and is bound to the rest of the code like this:

```
DB.defineConnectionManager(DefaultConnectionIdentifier, DBVendor)
```